# How to solve Error500 Http\Kernel::class on Laravel 5

Tags: laravel

Hi I have to install finished project created by laravel5 on my client'cloud (CentOS). Everything work find on my windows local host. But I got error500 on real server.

Some error clue:

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
$response = $kernel->handle(
$request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture());
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

This phpmyadmin screen sent from my client
[image]

Note that this is cloud server that is not my own. So I can not install composer / run command or install other libraries. Thank you for all answer.

Comment: whats your public path for the application for local server and production server?

Comment: I put all files outside (as picture https://ibb.co/VVycNXh ). So it should not setting more. I did the same both local and server.

Answer (score -1):

You have to change the vendor and bootstrap folder path in index.php on your current structure

change these two lines from index.php

**`require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';`**
 
**`$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';`**

to

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Comment: From this picture (https://ibb.co/VVycNXh , https://ibb.co/JmYMKWb). I set to => require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php'; <= Is it correct?.

Comment: yes it is. good to go.If it is not working then in your index.php
paste this at the top of the script
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); This will show you the actual error

Comment: Hi  Daniel, I already add that code on top of index.php. Before adding code, it's error 500. And after adding, It's just only white screen.

Comment: Man i tried it on my machine it works may be the issue in your .env file check the username & password and host of your DB

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I just checked. Server is empty Linux. I may need to do SSH remote access to install some dependencies. But no idea to go at this moment.

Comment: well i can help you in installing dependency if you want

Comment: Hi Daniel Masih, So much appreciated. I'll try by myself first.